# Check ActionBar's overflow popup is showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to check that the action overflow PopupMenu is now showing?

It is need for me when I trying to auto-hide ActionBar, and don't need to hide when ActionBar's overflow popup is showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override [`Activity.onMenuOpened`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onMenuOpened%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29) and [`Activity.onPanelClosed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPanelClosed%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29) to determine when the overflow menu or other sub-menus are showing, such as the [`ShareActionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html). Here's an example:

```
/** True if an options menu has been opened, false otherwise */
private boolean mMenuOpened;

@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    mMenuOpened = true;
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
    mMenuOpened = false;
}
```

**Alternatively**

`ActionBarView` subclasses `AbsActionBarView` which contains [`AbsActionBarView.isOverflowMenuShowing`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/AbsActionBarView.java#L197). Since these class are internal and hidden, you'll need to access it via reflection.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final int actionBarViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
    final View actionBarView = findViewById(actionBarViewId);

    actionBarView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(isOverflowMenuShowing(actionBarView));
        }
    }, 2500);
}

private static boolean isOverflowMenuShowing(View actionBarView) {
    try {
        final Class<?> abv = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView");
        final Method isOverflowShowing = abv.getMethod("isOverflowMenuShowing", new Class[] {});
        return (boolean) isOverflowShowing.invoke(actionBarView, new Object[] {});
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @kirik88 Come to find out, I completely overlooked `Activity.onMenuOpened` and `Activity.onPanelClosed`. You don't need to use reflection, I updated my answer.